# Method 'dealloc()' with Objective-C selector 'dealloc' conflicts with implicit deinitializer with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, swift

I was setting up [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar) in Swift. When I tried to convert

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [self stopFollowingScrollView];
}
```

to

```
func dealloc() {
    self.stopFollowingScrollView()
}
```

an error described in the question occurred. Could you tell me the reason for it and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In swift you need to rename `dealloc` to `deinit`, like this:

```
deinit {
 self.stopFollowingScrollView()
}
```